# Eclipse runs "Invoking 'Java Builder' on '/git'" - for a C++ project

Tags: c++, eclipse

I use Eclipse for C++ code that is eventually compiled on an IBM iSeries (a.k.a. AS/400).  Not even compiled on my Windows laptop.  I'm not sure where this came from but it is irritatingly frustrating.  When I refresh the project manually or Eclipse does so automatically, it is unacceptably slow to do so.  I eventually found that it was running this seemingly unnecessary process mentioned in the title.  What gives?  How did this thing get turned on in the first place?

Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: 2018-09 (4.9.0)
Build id: 20180917-1800
OS: Windows 10, v.10.0, x86_64 / win32
Java version: 1.8.0_181

Comment: It's probably something defined in the project somewhere. Personally, I decided Eclipse is great for Java dev but kind of sucks for C++. It was constantly doing weird shit and costing me hours.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the "Build Automatically" under the "Project" menu was checked.  Unchecking this seems to have cured my problem.